# Editing policy given new information

Tags: discussion, editing

If you give a correct answer, but someone gives a hint in a comment on how at a certain step in the solution a different approach would have shortened your answer, what is the best way to edit your answer? I have been adding an addendum under the old answer with the heading "Edit:", but I don't know whether it's better to just edit the entire thing and only give the newer streamlined answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of writing answers is to explain something.  It is not to give a chronological report of how your thoughts went, and how you interacted with a commenter. So, the answers should be optimized with the former goal in mind. Rewrite as many times as needed, and as thoroughly as needed.

Comment: Sometimes the thought process can be more helpful than a slick answer that might be harder to follow.